# SQL Server- SUM Subquery each other

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to ask for a little help in ***SQL Server***.

How can I sum each other subquery and display it into one column.

I tested to add the subqueries in the `SELECT` statement, but, then I realize that I don't know how to sum between them, then I added them to the `FROM` statement to see If I adding them up in the `SELECT` statement could but work, but it didn't.

*the idea is to substract B with A for each CodUbic*.

1. 'A' for purchases ($),
2. 'B' for returned products ($)

   SELECT
   MONTH(FechaE) AS Mes,
   YEAR(FechaE) AS Ano,
   CodUbic,
   TipoFac,
   (SumFacA + SumFacB)

   ```
   FROM 
       dbo.SAFACT,
       (SELECT SUM(Monto) FROM dbo.SAFACT WHERE TipoFac IN ('A')) AS SumFacA,
       (SELECT -SUM(Monto) FROM dbo.SAFACT WHere TipoFac IN ('B')) AS SumFacB

   WHERE
       TipoFac IN ('A', 'B')
   GROUP BY  
       MONTH(FechaE),
       YEAR(FechaE),
       CodUbic,
       TipoFac

   ORDER BY 
       YEAR(FechaE) DESC, 
       MONTH(FechaE);
   ```

Expected Result:

```
    Mes   Ano    CodUbic            TotalSum
   ----------------------------------------------------
     1    2022    0002-1     #### (Due the sum of A-B)   
     1    2022    0004-1     #### (Due the sum of A-B)
     2    2022    0002-1     #### (Due the sum of A-B)
     2    2022    0004-1     #### (Due the sum of A-B) 
    ...    ...     ...           ...
```

Comment: It's 2022, why have you *not* adotped the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax yet? It's been about for **30 years**.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste your sample data as formatted text into your request instead. Then also please show the expected result.

Comment: @Larnu please, be a little more specific, i'm still making through my path into SQL.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I deleted the image. 

The expected result It's an error, I cannot sum the subqueries each other.

Comment: Now please add the sample data you had in the picture as text to your query. And then show also the expected result for this data. "Expected result" means the result you want to get.

Comment: *"be a little more specific"* About what? If you search "ANSI-92 Explicit Join Syntax" you'll find **exactly** what I am talking about.  See [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: As to comma-separated joins: Whoever taught you this syntax should better quit teaching. They can mention "this is how we did this some decades ago", but they should teach you explicit joins now (`[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are finally showing the expected result. It doesn't contain a column for TipoFac. This means, you want a result row per month and CodUbic, not per month, CodUbic, and TipoFac. Change your `GROUP BY` clause accordingly.

You get the difference between A and B with conditional aggregation (`CASE WHEN` inside the aggregation function).

```
SELECT
    MONTH(FechaE) AS Mes, YEAR(FechaE) AS Ano, CodUbic,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN monto ELSE -monto END) AS diff
FROM 
    dbo.SAFACT
WHERE
    TipoFac IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY  
    MONTH(FechaE), YEAR(FechaE), CodUbic
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(FechaE) DESC, MONTH(FechaE), CodUbic
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(FechaE) AS Mes,
    YEAR(FechaE) AS Ano,
    CodUbic,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN ISNULL(Monto,0) ELSE 0 END) -
    SUM(CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'B' THEN ISNULL(Monto,0) ELSE 0 END)

FROM 
    dbo.SAFACT

WHERE
    TipoFac IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY  
    MONTH(FechaE),
    YEAR(FechaE),
    CodUbic
    
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(FechaE) DESC, 
    MONTH(FechaE);
```

Comment: Almost but no :c, it shows ¨NULL¨ values

Comment: Should that be a joke? Using in clauses with just one value is really slow, bad to read and should never be used.

Comment: @ArnaldoData i updated the query to return 0 if no data.

Comment: @JonasMetzler there are 2 clauses 'A' and 'B'.

Comment: @Dordi I don't know exactly where's the problem is... I copied the code as you wrote it, ran it and the colum where the values should be summed, all rows says: "NULL"

Comment: Your query can still produce NULL values in case there are null values in the column "monto". You could do a coalesce to set them to 0, but it's not clear if this is intended. Overall, the desired output is not clear and should be clarified before.

Comment: @ArnaldoData: Dordi edited his query after my comment, therefore you can't see anymore what I was writing about ;)

Comment: The query gets the single rows, e.g. a row with TipoFac = 'A' and monto = 100. The calculation for this row is then 100 - NULL which is NULL. If it where a B row, it would be NULL - 100 which is also NULL.

Comment: @JonasMetzler you're right, i updated the query accordingly

Comment: I added into the post, the expected result... 

Yep, but I checked and there isn't NULL values, because If I sum all the As and then sum all the Bs into one colum as it is right now, there is not any null valuel.

I just need A with B by the CodUbic.

E.g.       

0002-1 

For January
A = 500
B= 100 (B is returned products, so the $ is in negative form)

Monto =  400 (A-B)

Comment: @ArnaldoData i remarked that we are adding `TipoFac` in the group by we shouldn't to have your desired result